# How to POST a file with fetch in a functional React component?

Tags: reactjs, rest, flask, fetch-api

How I do you send a file from a React app to a Flask server for processing?

I have a React app using functional components with the following form component:

```
export function UploadComponent() {


  const onSubmit = async (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const response = await fetch("/api/upload", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        inputFile: ev.target.inputFile.value
      }
    })
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("Post sent!")
    }
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input id="inputFile" type="file" />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

In my Flask API, I have the following route:

```
@app.route('/api/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files.get('inputFile') # also tried request.files['inputFile']
    # process file and define response
    return {"message": "some response message"}
```

However, even though the client performs a post request, the Flask API does not receive anything, i.e. file is None.
It seems to work like this for text fields but I can't get it to work with files.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer somewhere else. The fix goes like this:

```
export function UploadComponent() {
  const onSubmit = async (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('inputFile', ev.target.inputFile.files[0]);
    const response = await fetch("/api/upload", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    });
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log("Post sent!")
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input id="inputFile" type="file" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```